# Sonatype scan shows Spring-Web is vulnerable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, owasp, sonatype

My company's Sonatype scan shows Spring-Web is vulnerable even for the latest version (currently 5.2.3.RELEASE).

It reads:

> "Found security vulnerability CVE-2016-1000027 with severity 9.8".

I noticed [CVE-2016-1000027](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2016-1000027) is added to the NATIONAL VULNERABILITY DATABASE
on 01/02/2020, and it is in regards to

> "Spring Framework 4.1.4 suffers from a potential remote code execution
> (RCE) issue if used for Java deserialization of untrusted data".

**Is this an obsolete ticket or has it not be resolved after 4 years?**

Comment: Sonatype does extended analysis of the source of vulnerable components, so it isn’t unusual for us to find that a CVE’s information isn’t complete.  That said, I would suggest contacting Sonatype support if you have doubts, since Nexus IQ Server is a licensed and supported product.

Comment: Seems unresolved: https://www.tenable.com/security/research/tra-2016-20 - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434

Comment: spring-web current version 5.3.20 still shows the vulnerability CVE-2016-1000027 by sonatype with highest policy threat score of 7. A fix to this will really help the community.

Answer (score 16):

This issue is resolved from a Spring Framework point of view, [see my latest comment summarizing the situation on that issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-744519525). Your application is only vulnerable if you're using `HTTPInvokerServiceExporter` or `RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter` and reading data from untrusted sources.

Deserializing Java code from untrusted sources is a well-known problem in Java (so, all Java applications and Frameworks!), and this feature might be removed in future Java versions.

Given the nature of this security problem (there's no way to "fix it" besides removing the classes, which will be done in the next major version of Spring Framework), contacting your vendor or your security team is the best course of action. The Spring team is happy to help the community with this matter by providing more context on that issue if needed.