# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern

Tags: spring, security, nosuchmethoderror

I found a security vulnerability during the sonatype library scan in `spring-beans` and `spring-context` `5.2.12.Release` version. But when I upgraded its parent library `spring-webmvc` to `5.3.14` to get rid of the vulnerability I got a new runtime error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern`.

Comment: Don't... Never mix jars from different versions of Spring that is trouble waiting to happen, upgrade all the jars and make sure that other frameworks you are using are actually compatible (you might need to upgrade those as well!).

Comment: I am not able to upgrade all due to CVE security vulnerabilities in different versions

Comment: You simply **must** upgrade all versions... You cannot upgrade 1 jar of the framework, you have to match the versions... If not you will get weird and hard to debug issues not to mention incompatibilites... So you need to upgrade all parts of Spring to the same version, unless yuou want other "nice" issues.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by upgrading spring-web and restricting it to a specific version

```
implementation (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web' ) {
        version{
            strictly '5.3.20'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Again you shouldn't upgrade 1 part of the framework you **must** upgrade all parts of the framework.. If not you will run into hard and difficult to debug issues due to incompatibilites... This is only a road to more issues.

Comment: I totally agree with you, this is how it should be. But complying with our security team requirements is making it harder. If any libraries embedded in our application has a highest policy threat as per sonatype nexus, we are not allowed to deploy our applications.

Comment: Where have I said you should violate that... I'm merely stating you shouldn't upgrade 1 part of the framework but upgrade all parts of that framework. So if you upgrade `spring-web` to a higher version all spring dependencies should be upgraded... If not you will run into weird issues (and then don't come back to stackoverflow asking question why it doesn't work or has issues). So in this case all your core spring dependencies (context, beans, aop etc.etc.) should be set to the same version.

Comment: We are facing similar issues as in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193808/sonatype-scan-shows-spring-web-is-vulnerable, collaboration between spring community and sonatype to fix it and update sonatype vulnerabilites may help the community.