# Unsafe deserialization in Spring RemoteInvocationSerializingExporter could lead to remote code execution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following dependency and its causing the above issue

```
<properties>
   <spring-boot.version>2.7.10</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonatype scan shows Spring-Web is vulnerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193808/sonatype-scan-shows-spring-web-is-vulnerable)